# Possible to insert a row into a table if a number is not in a comma delineated list in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I currently am making 2 database calls to basicly select a value from one table(**marks_nums_options**), if a value is not in a comma delineated list (basically an exclude list) in this table, then an entry is added to my main database table(**mark_nums**)

**What I'm doing now**

My current SQL code to add the database entry:

```
SELECT excludetid FROM mark_nums_options WHERE userid = '$userid' LIMIT 1
```

excludetid is a comma delineated list like this: 33,887,1,774

I then use PHP to make sure my $object is not in the $excludetid array by first changing the $excludetid comma list into a PHP array and check if the value is in the array

```
!in_array($object,$excludetid)
```

If its not in there then I insert a set of values into my main **marks_nums** table

```
INSERT INTO marks_nums (userid, date, type, object, objecttitle, link, pid, tid)          
VALUES ('$userid', '$dateline', '$type', '$object', '$objecttitle', '$link', '$pid', '$tid')
```

**What I'm hoping to do**

I'm hoping to basicly put this all into one single database query, so have the insert into call check to see if $object is a number inside a comma delineated list $excludetid but the catch is that $excludetid is in another table called marks_nums_options.

Is this possible?  Is it worth even doing?  I was hoping by combining it all into 1 I would be hitting the database less and therefore have a performance improvement

Thanks!

Comment: you can use JOIN or IN() to do this without having to do them in PHP, and it's straight forward as well. But you only showed marks_nums_options and it has excludetid, which means you're reading excludetid to get values from another source. Then you'll insert the gathered values into marks_nums. So, we need to know the tables schema for them, it will be much helpful to give you a proper answer that would fit your needs

Answer (score 0):

> I was hoping by combining it all into 1 I would be hitting the database less and therefore have a performance improvement

Querying the database twice is an insignificant extra performance cost, compared to the much greater cost of the table-scan caused by searching a comma-delimited list for a specific value.

You can't run an efficient query searching for a value in a comma-separated list, because you can't index such a search. It has to search the hard way, searching every row in the table.

This would be a much easier query, and have better performance, if you stored your list of excluded tid values in a separate table, one value per row.

Don't be penny-wise and pound-foolish.

Comment: Makes sense!  Only caveat is i'm actually searching by a known $userid (indexed).  Once the result row is found (based on userid), one of the columns is the comma delineated list, so mysql shouldnt be searching the entire table for the item in a comma list

Comment: Or you could store it in a table keyed by **userid, tid** and then you can write the query more easily. It's just a bad idea to store data in comma-separated lists when you intend to access individual elements.